# Can't open some PowerPoint files from email's attachment with my app

Tags: ios, email, share

I need to share all document, image and video from mail attachment to my app, but unfortunately some document where missing my app from share on panel. Here it is my info.plist's document type.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft PowerPoint</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt</string>
                    <string>org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>OpenDocument Presentation</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>org.oasis.opendocument.presentation</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft Excel</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft Word</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.wordml</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>OpenDocument Text</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>org.oasis.opendocument.text</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Audio</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.audio</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.3gpp</string>
            <string>public.3gpp2</string>
            <string>public.mpeg-4</string>
            <string>public.avi</string>
            <string>com.apple.quicktime-movie</string>
            <string>public.mpeg</string>
            <string>public.movie</string>
            <string>public.video</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp image</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

For example i can't share [this powerpoint](http://www.unm.edu/~unmvclib/powerpoint/pptexamples.ppt)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your app to be on the list for any type of file, you can use the generic UTI `public.data`...

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Document</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```